# How to find the distinct values with row count?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need small requirement and i have following input.

```
ReportId   ReportName

1            Adhoc
1            Adhoc
2            Financial
2            Financial
2            Financial
3            Dynamic
3            Dynamic
3            Dynamic
3            Dynamic
```

and I need out put like this

```
ReportId   ReportName
    2    Adhoc
    3    Financial
    4    Adhoc
```

Please give me the solution

Comment: I don't get the output. What do you want?

Comment: It looks like a count, but why is Adhoc in there twice? I'm guessing it's a typo, as "Dynamic" has 4 entries which would match.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*),reportname from tbl group by reportname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(ReportName) as howMany, ReportName 
from reports
group by ReportName 
order by howMany asc
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for count in the first column then this will help:

```
SELECT Count(ReportName), ReportName FROM Table1 group by ReportName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mention wrongly in your question you want output like this.

```
ReportId   ReportName
    2    Adhoc
    3    Financial
    4    Dynamic
```

The below query will give you the above output.

```
select Reportname, count(1) as ReportIdcount
from   Reportstb
group by reportname;
```